# Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding - jquery mobile with knockout

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I get the this error in console: "Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding"
I use to wep api, jquery mobile and knockoutjs in my project. Wep api is running smoothly.

```
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/photoswipe/klass.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mmenu.min.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/photoswipe/code.photoswipe.jquery-3.0.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/o-script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/knockout-3.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ViewModel = function () {
        this.allAd = ko.observableArray([]);
        this.lastAd = ko.observableArray([]);
    };

    var vm = new ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);

    $.getJSON("http://localhost:54027/api/ad/allads", function (data) {
       vm.allAd(data)
    })

    $.getJSON("http://localhost:54027/api/ad/lastads", function (data) {
        vm.lastAd(data)
    })
})
  </script>

  <div data-role="main" id="content2">
        <div class="subHeader"><i class="i-home i-small"></i>Tüm İlanlar</div>
        <input id="filterBasic-input" data-type="search">

        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-input="#filterBasic-input" data-bind="forech:allAd">
            <li>
                <a data-bind="attr:{href: page2}" href="#page2" data-transition="flip">

                    <h2 data-bind="text:Title"></h2>
                    <p data-bind="text:Price"></p>
                </a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

What's the problem? Where is it? Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data-bind="forech:allAd"
```

`forech` should be `foreach`

If you still get errors, the most likely cause is that your server api isn't returning a JavaScript array in the format you are expecting. Make sure the data returned from the `$.getJSON()` call is in fact a JavaScript array of objects. It could be JSON in the form of a string, which would need to be parsed into JavaScript. It could be an object that contains an array, etc. If you confirm that it is in fact an array with objects, make sure that **page2**, **Title**, and **Price** are in fact properties of each object in the array.

It would be helpful if you posted the full error. It should tell you which binding contains an error.